# PHP neat way of displaying results, without duplicated heading

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and I want to have the output that only outputs the unique heading in "id" and "output" heading.

```
$job_rows = array(
                array("id" => 1, "output" => "file01", "output_type" => "FBX"),
                array("id" => 1, "output" => "file01", "output_type" => "JPG"),
                array("id" => 1, "output" => "file03", "output_type" => "JPL"),
                array("id" => 2, "output" => "file05", "output_type" => "FBX"),
                array("id" => 2, "output" => "file06", "output_type" => "JPX"),
                array("id" => 2, "output" => "file06", "output_type" => "JPG"),
                array("id" => 3, "output" => "file010", "output_type" => "FBX"),
                array("id" => 3, "output" => "file010", "output_type" => "JPA")
            );
```

Output that I want to accomplished.

```
ID : 1
    OUTPUTS :
    file01  FBX
            JPG
    file03  JPL
ID : 2
    OUTPUTS :
    file05  FBX
    file06  JPX
            JPG
ID : 3
    OUTPUTS :
    file010 FBX
            JPA


.. etc
```

basically combining the common IDs during echo'ing the results on page. Thanks

Comment: maybe you can rework on your query

Comment: Strange. Cann't understand why you get same id's

Comment: I agree with Ibu. It might be more adventageous to change your queries and work with the revised output. If you'd rather not, there are always ways. -- Also it might be useful to show your query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that:

```
$ID = -999;
$FILENAME = "";
foreach ($job_rows as $key => $value) {    
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        print ($ID === $value['id'])?"":"ID : ".$value['id']."<br />";
        print ($FILENAME === "".$value['output'])? "":$value['output']." ";
        print ($k == 'output_type')?$v."<br />":"";
        $ID = $value['id'];
        $FILENAME = "".$value['output'];
    }
}
```

and it gives the output exactly like you wanted:

```
ID : 1
file01 FBX
JPG
file03 JPL
ID : 2
file05 FBX
file06 JPX
JPG
ID : 3
file010 FBX
JPA
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new array/datastructure based on the results using the `id` and `output` as keys:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($job_rows as $row) {
  $newArray[ $row['id'] ][ $row['output'] ][] = $row['output_type'];
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just keep track of the ID and output values, make sure that the IDs are sorted first. You may have to do some extra coding to get the tabbing to be correct.

```
<?php

$currentID = null;
$currentFile = null;
foreach($items as $i) {
    if($currentID != $i['id']) {
         $currentID = $id;
         $currentFile = null;
         echo 'ID : '.$id."\n";
    }
    echo "\tOUTPUTS : \n";
    $file = $i['output'];
    if($currentFile != $file) {
        echo "\t\t$file\t{$i['output_type']}\n";
        $currentFile = $file;
    }
    else {
        echo "\t\t\t\t{$i['output_type']}\n";
    }
}

?>
```